# Does riding a mount influence resources detection ability?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, world-of-warcraft-classic

In World of Warcraft Classic/Retail, when riding a mount, does it make any changes to time and/or distance a resource (herb, ore, etc.) is being shown on mini map?

If any, it may be in-game (ex. higher speed affects effective range of detection) or out of game (ex. higher speed means less updates per traveled distance which may display resource later than usual.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second guess is correct.

Once you are in range, your client will take a little bit of time to register that there is a resource nearby.

So, if you are travelling faster, resources often appear near (because by the time it is loaded, you have reached them) or not at all (because by the time it is loaded, you went back out of range).

Comment: That seems resonable but is there any official (or unoficiall but confirmed) source of this claim?

Comment: Not really, I've just noticed it by playing myself (and leveling a couple of jobs). It's obvious when you start to have latency issues and gathering spots appear on the map after you already scanned an area.

Comment: Same issue happen with everything in fact (NPCs, Monsters or players). You can specially notice it when using the Flying mounts.

Comment: Is the speed of Classic mounts enough to notice this? I am asking about both epic and non-epic

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Yes. It could even happen when simply running if your latency is high enough.